# max length of the string in Oracle regexp_substr and regexp_replace function

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I try to find what is the maximum length of a text as input to the Oracle regexp functions.

thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303

Comment: the source_char could be one of the data type such as char etc. so the biggest one is NCLOB but if I type a text lek '1234.......' could be it be of the the size of NCLOB ?